# Django Multi-subdomain cookies

Tags: django, cookies, subdomain, django-sessions

I have a website built with Django on beta.domain.com . To interact with the server, I am using my API, which is also built with Django, located on api.domain.com .

When a user loads beta.domain.com, api.comain.com is loaded in an iframe, and all the server-side communication runs through that iframe.

I want these two subdomains to use the same sessions. With a quick search on the internet, I found about SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN . In the settings file of both applications, I've set this value to '.domain.com'. But still, I couldn't achieve what I wanted.

I can successfully write session data with the application on beta.domain.com, but I can not read the same session on api.domain.com.

Could this be because of the user disabling cookies from 3rd party sites? (In this case, api.domain.com is seen as a 3rd party site). Even if the user disables 3rd party sites from *writing* cookies, shouldn't I be able to *read* cookies?

Comment: Please help a fellow brother who has to work on a Saturday night